# Get informations of a list of venues

Tags: api, list, foursquare

I have a list of venues id and I want to get informations about each venue. I have to make a request for each venue with https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID ?

There are no way to make one request for the list of venues ?

Thanks

Comment: it may be more efficient to use [search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) api to fetch a list of information of venues if those venues are already close to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to provide a list of venues to get back venue details. (As Martin mentions, there's a /multi/ endpoint, but each sub-request still counts against your rate limits).

Foursquare allows you to cache venue details for up to 30 days, so you be sure to do local caching to avoid unnecessary calls to the API. See the **Retention** section of https://foursquare.com/legal/api/platformpolicy for more details

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't seem to be listed in the current version of the [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/), there is a [`multi` endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/multi/multi) which allows you to combine (up to) five API requests into one. Hopefully this will help somewhat with reducing the number of calls you need to make to get the details for the list of venues.